# Displaying an array in angular.js

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, sorting

I'm sending data of to a php file and the php file is processing and doing a sql search and its bringing back a list in a for each statement, for example: ryan, jack, billy, sarah

etc

when I echo the response, in angular, i'm getting all the names joined up like: ryanjackbillysarah

How can I show this on the page in a list so like: 
Ryan 
Jack
Billy 
Sarah

This is my php

```
$result = mysqli_query( $connect, $sql);

if($result){
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    $list .= $row["firstname"];

  }
}

echo $list;
```

This is my angular success, function.

```
     // Success call back function.
       request.then(function successCallback(response) {


            //alert(response.data);
          alert(response.data);



       },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use json_encode in your php to return a JSON to angular.

```
$result = mysqli_query( $connect, $sql);

if($result){
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    $list[] = $row["firstname"];

  }
}

echo json_encode($list);
```

Comment: Ah thanks appreciate it. Its echo it out like ryanjackbillysarah is there anyway i can separate each one ?

Comment: Yes, just put your response in an array

$list[] = $row["firstname"];

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are concatenating each list item in a string. You have to separate them in some way or return the list and make the foreach angular .

I think that's what I do not understand much about php . Try putting a space.

```
    $result = mysqli_query( $connect, $sql);

if($result){
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    $list .= $row["firstname"] . ' ';

  }
}

echo $list;
```